# What is the difference between DEALER and ROUTER socket archetype in ZeroMQ?

Tags: networking, zeromq

What is the difference between the **`ROUTER`** and the **`DEALER`** socket archetypes in zmq?

And which should I use, if I have a server, which is receiving messages and a client, which is sending messages? The server will never send a message to a client.

**EDIT:** I forgot to say that there can be several instances of the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For details on **`ROUTER/DEALER`** Formal Communication Pattern, do not hesitate to [**consult the API documentation**](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-socket). There are many features important for `ROUTER/DEALER` ( `XREQ/XREP` ) that have nothing beneficial for your indicated use-case.

---

### Many just send, just one just listens?

Given **N**-clients purely **`.send()`** messages to **1**-server, which exclusively **`.recv()`** messages, but never sends any message back,
the design may benefit from a **`PUB/SUB`** Formal Communication Pattern.

In case some other preferences outweight the trivial approach, one may setup a more complex "wireing", using another one-way type of infrastructure, based on **`PUSH/PULL`**, and use a reverse setup **`PUB/SUB`**, where each new client, the **`PUB`** side, **`.connect()`**-s to the **`SUB`**-side, given a server-side **`.bind()`** access-point is on a known, static IP address and the client self-advertises on this signalling channel, that it is alive ( keep-alive with IP-address:port#, where the server-side ought initiate a new **`PUSHtoPULL.connect()`** setup onto the client-advertised, **`.bind()`**-ready **`PULL`**-side access point.

---

### Complex? Rather a limitless tool, only our imagination is our limit.

After some time, one realises all the powers of multi-functional SIG/MSG-infrastructure, so do not hesitate to experiment and re-use the elementary archetypes in more complex, mutually-cooperating distributed systems computing.